# How to know if the Variable is Categorical or Numerical if all it contains is Digits?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, data-analysis

I have a dataset which has several `Variables`.

I want to determine that how can we judge for a variable if it is categorical or numerical other than the method of unique value counts, as for instance one of my variable Disease Type has 31 Unique Values whereas other `Variable Distance` from `Office` has 25 Unique Values, both in the form of numbers.

Comment: Check `df.dtypes`

Comment: Did you try looking at the dtype?

Comment: @SandeepKadapa Yes, by default both of them are int. But as part of Exploratory Data Analysis, I've to convert then into suitable categories.

Comment: @coldspeed Yes, by default both of them are int. But as part of Exploratory Data Analysis, I've to convert then into suitable categories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer, is: your knowledge of the problem domain / application domain will tell you.

There are some differences that you look for, but to apply these differences, you will still have to use some domain knowledge (sometimes common sense).

The following are some differences which will help you distinguish:

1. For categorical variables, the set of permitted values is usually **fixed**, and rarely changes, if at all. In contrast, for numeric variable, the set of values can change, for example, when you receive a new record for the same dataset.
2. Numeric variables **can potentially have** values that are not round integers. In your example, even though "distance from office" *happens to have* integer values, that could be purely incidental, or could have been a choice made by some one about how much numeric precision they want in the data.
3. For categorical variables, it usually doesn't make sense to talk of averages. For example, there are 2 types of diabetes called Type 1, Type 2, but it just doesn't make sense to talk of an average of these types (Type 1.2357?).
4. Ask yourself this thumb-rule question: When I perform my data analysis can I express my inferences in terms of specific values of this variable? How about ranges of this variable ("0 to 5 km", "5 to 10 km", etc). For example, can I report any inferences from my data analysis that says "Those whose distance from office is 123, are prone to be successful in their career"? That specific value sounds silly, right? In contrast, if it were a categorical variable such as Type 2 Diabetes, you can always make inferences in terms of the specific value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the "unique counts" method did not appeal as a solution for the original poster. However, I will still like to show how to use it and present my quick solution in numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,1.0,4.0,3.0]) 
unique_a = np.unique(a) 
if (unique_a.astype(int) == unique_a).sum() == len(unique_a):             
      print("Categorical variable") 
else:    
      print("Not a categorical variable")
```

Basically, by casting the variable type to integer and checking if it is still identical to the original values we can determine whether it is categorical or not.

Answer (score -1):

`<dataframename>.info()` will give the total count of each variable along with whether it is non-null and its datatype like `float64`,`object`,`int64` etc

Comment: Yes, dataframe.info() shall give the datatype what the data is by default as loaded into dataframe. What I'm looking for is a logical or numerical way to figure out what the type of Variable is, by having analysis onto the data it contains, which in my case is all digit, so that I can convert it into the adequate type.